# Hibernate Session Saving same object twice

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hello Every time I try to save an object in Hibernate , it is saving twice can anyone  help me.

Note: The below log messages are displayed after  `session.saveOrUpdate(register);` line

**My Code is**

```
Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.saveOrUpdate(register);
            transaction.commit();
            session.close();
            return true;
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
```

**My log is**

Hibernate: `insert into UserRegister (address1, address2, bloodGroup, addressCity, dateOfBirth, firstName, gender, lastName, password, phoneNumber, addressState, userEmail, userName, addresszipCode) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Hibernate: `insert into UserRegister (address1, address2, bloodGroup, addressCity, dateOfBirth, firstName, gender, lastName, password, phoneNumber, addressState, userEmail, userName, addresszipCode) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

My entity is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserRegister", uniqueConstraints = {
@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -77886191777123344L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 11)
    private int userID;

    @Column(name = "firstName", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "userName", nullable = false)
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "gender", nullable = false)
    private String gender;

    @Column(name = "dateOfBirth", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp dateOfBirth;

    @Column(name = "bloodGroup", nullable = true)
    private String bloodGroup;

    @Column(name = "userEmail", nullable = false)
    private String userEmail;

    @Column(name = "phoneNumber", nullable = false)
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "address1", nullable = false)
    private String address1;

    @Column(name = "address2")
    private String address2;

    @Column(name = "addressCity")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "addressState")
    private String state;

    @Column(name = "addresszipCode")
    private String zipCode;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="userID")
    private List<UserMessages> userMessages;
```

My UserMessages Entity is

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "UserMessages", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})})
public class UserMessages implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -77886191777123344L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 11)
    private int messageID;

    @Column(name = "fromName", nullable = false)
    private String fromName;

    @Column(name = "message", nullable = false)
    private String message;

    @Column(name = "messageTime", nullable = false)
    private Timestamp messageTime;

    @Column(name = "fromPhoneNumber", nullable = false)
    private String fromPhoneNumber;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userID", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private User user;
```

Comment: Could you show the mappings for register and associated entities (if any)?

Comment: can you please look at the entity

Comment: you're using cascadetype.all. Is it possible that you specified the same on the inverse side (UserMessages) as well?

Comment: Is association with UserMessages bidirectional? (Or better, could you post the mappings for UserMessages as well?)

Comment: @DraganBozanovic , please look at  the entity

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice at first that you are actually declaring User side as the association owner.

Comment: Is the `userMessages` list empty when you save the user?

Comment: No the list is not empty. i Dont know what the problem is .

Comment: Could you try with an empty list, just to make sure that the issue is (not) related to the association?